# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.148.2.106' (using password: YES) in Android

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, xampp

i'm trying to connect my android app to mysql database with JDBC , but i keep getting this exception when i test the app in a real device and i really can't figure it out 
i have tried to create a new user in XAMPP and granting all privileges to the user , but none of that worked out

could somebody help me with that please,  i'm really blocked ?

My activity code :

```
public class SuccessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String url="jdbc:mysql://192.148.2.114:3306/gtransport";
    public static final String user="root";
    public static final String pass="a123";
    TextView EmailShow;
    TextView Etat;
    String EmailHolder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_success);


        EmailShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email_textview);
        Etat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.etat_textview);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        EmailHolder = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME);
        EmailShow.setText(EmailHolder);
        new MyTask().execute();


    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private  String V_etat="";



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                String sql="select * from Chauffeur where email=?";

                PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1,EmailHolder);

                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()) {

                    V_etat = (rs.getString("nom"));

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }






            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Etat.setText(V_etat);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }




}
```

here's my users table in xampp :
[image]

Comment: You have to allow connections inside sql database configuration for network ranges, or allow all IPs

Comment: @GGK how can i do that please ?

Comment: use the command to allow remote access `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<user>'@'10.3.%' IDENTIFIED BY '<Password>' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem !
i figured out that when i was creating the user i typed the password by myself,and at the same time i forgot and clicked on "generate password button" which generates an automatic password for u .

so anyone who is facing similar problem pay attention to that while creating a new user !